# Resource Editor to applicate in a C/C++ prg but not the ResEdit of Melander

Tags: c, c++11, resources

I'm searching for a Resource Editor that can handle a Stringtable in 3 different languages and permits  to design a Dialogbox. I formerly developed in Borland C++ and would like to find a Resource Editor similar. In Melander I don't even find how to build a Stringtable or add a Dialogbox.
I want to write the C++ code in MinGW.
I'm searching for a GUI-Resourse-Editor. Not a prompt-based Editor.
Because I don't want to position the controlls in a prompt, and not size the dialog-window this way above all I need to size the controlls for the translations in the 3 language.

Comment: MinGW comes with "rc", the resource compiler. Read its documentation, and any other document linked there you see fit.

Comment: @busybee I didn't find any executable "RC" Is it to start in DOS?

Comment: Sorry, I misspelled the executable, it's "windres.exe", and yes, that is a command line program.

Comment: @busybee Found MinGW/bin/windres.exe but it start a DOS-Prompt, what are one to enter to start any thing. I tried "help" but nothing hapened, I expected a list of orders or key word. Does this executable really start a Ressource Editor with graphical surface?

Comment: @Busybee, thank you I found MinGW/bin/windres.exe but it starts a DOS-Prompt how do I go on and does this thing a Ressource Editor with graphical surface to design a Dialog-Box? As a recompense I'll publish here the complete code for a Turing-Bomb, it doesn't explode, it is to decifer German message cifered with the legendary ENIGMA. My program is in German, English and Spanish, so I need a stringtable for all Lables in 3 Languages, hopefully "windres.exe" support to build up this stringtable.

Comment: <opinion>The professional way of creating resources if to provide a source code for the resource compiler. GUIs are for mouse-addicted noobs.</opinion> "windres" tells you its options, if you call it (as usual) by `windres --help`. It takes a source file and produces an object file. If you look for a GUI program, please [edit] your question to explicitly tell us. -- However, recommendations are out of scope here on StackOverflow, I'm sure you will find some by your favorite web search engine. Having said this, I remember that "MinGWStudio" came with one, but it is not updated since 2005 or so.

Comment: @busybee yes, MinGWStudio has a resource-Editor, but based on a DOS-Prompt-Programm.

Comment: @busybee are you sure you worked with windres: I think it was what you can down load here https://www.heise.de/download/product/resedit-69790 all the downloads is finally a ResEdit.exe and all are GUIs. But I cannot for my String-Table create my own IDs, immedially in the installationprocess I could create a String-Table and define the language as Spanish-Spain, but because I couldn't create my own IDs I coudn't insert a String and I dindn't findout how to add a entry to this table. Now I don't know how I could create the String-Table and I can't find the created resource.

Comment: During the installationprocess I saw the error-messages, windows.h and another header was not found, hmm the windows-carpet is in my path, more one can't do.

Comment: windres came with MinGW, I didn't download anything extra. Just type its name in the shell (given that your PATH is set).

Comment: @busybee yes, my path contains MinGW/bin, where I saw windres.exe, so the shell should find it better than me!

Comment: @Busybee Hi overthere with this one http://www.angusj.com/resourcehacker/#download I at least could create a resource-file with 2 String-table and define the language in ResEdit I never came upto there.

Comment: While this is nice to know, it's still true that recommendations are off-topic here. Anyway, thanks for sharing! I hope I remember the next time I need such a tool.

Comment: Hello busybee I entered at windres compile C:\Users\Wolfg\Documents\Programmierung\MinGW\MinGW_Projekt\Turing_Bombe\Turing_bombe.rc

Comment: I confirme with return but nothing happend, no errormessage, no confirmation that te compiling was executed.

Comment: If you have another issue, please feel free to post a new question. You might want to read some of the [help] to refresh how this site works. It is not a forum.